# Manage subnetting from simple router

Tags: networking, subnet

I want to setup two different subnets in the same physical network with one router, these are my questions:
Let's assume I want the first subnet like 192.168.1.0-254 and the second subnet like 192.168.2.0-254.

1. How to setup the router and the clients for achieve this task?
2. Can these network communicate each other?
3. Which is the difference between this kind of setup and VLANs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to setup the router and the clients for achieve this task?

That depends on the router. On low-end routers, it may be impossible to have the router do anything but ignore one of the subnets. On more flexible routers, you may be able to assign a "secondary" address to the Ethernet interface.

> Can these network communicate each other?

If the router is the default gateway for machines in both subnets, it will route traffic between the two networks. Otherwise, normal unicast IP traffic will not pass directly between subnets. Broadcast traffic will be seen by all machines.

> Which is the difference between this kind of setup and VLANs?

With a VLAN setup, the machines don't see packets for the other network at all. It's essentially as if they were carried over separate cables. VLANs isolate non-IP traffic as well.

Comment: Another thing to mention is that without any kind of L2 separation (be it different physical interfaces or VLAN interfaces on the router), using DHCP for automatic address assignments to the clients will be a major hassle as the major criterion for relating a DHCP scope to a broadcast domain is the primary interface address of the DHCP server/relay the client request has been received at. Having more than one address at an interface, creates ambiguities which can be resolved, but usually mean a lot of manual work (e.g. reservations for each and every client).

Answer (score 0):

Setup completely depends on the model of router.

If this is your typical SOHO router, you will probably not be able to do this. But again, that depends on the model. If it's a business-grade router or firewall, two routed interfaces should be able to talk to each other.

A VLAN is a virtual LAN. This means that the layer 3 interface is virtual, which allows you to assign any port you want to a VLAN, or even trunk multiple VLANs to a switch. With a router, you're creating a physical layer 3 interface to route traffic.

Comment: I know that the setup depends from router, but I ask how manage the network IP and subnet mask from router and from clients.